# What's the suggested pattern to catch Unsubscription Error in Rx

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Come to an use case that I might have some error thrown when unsubscribing, and it cannot be caught by the catch operator. Besides putting a try catch in unsubscription handler any other good approach? and if its try caught does it still complete and kill the stream?

```
const streawm = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  return () => { throw "error"; };
});

const subscribe = streawm.catch(e=>Rx.Observable.of(e))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val),
  e=>{} ,
  e=>{console.log("finally");});

setTimeout(() => {
  subscribe.unsubscribe();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The call to `unsubscribe` itself will see the error thrown synchronously, so you could wrap that call in `try`/`catch` - e.g. `try { subscribe.unsubscribe(); } catch (error) { ... }`But would you do with such an unexpected error anyway?

Comment: it just when you chain combine slices  together, one of the stream meet the unsubscribe error, wonder how to resume the stream. try{ }cach(e){ subscribe again?}

Comment: I don't think you should be attempting to catch anything thrown from an `unsubscribe` implementation. If it's your's, you should fix it. If it's someone else's you should report it. If it cannot be fixed, then it's an error that cannot be expected and should be left unhandled.

Comment: I don'[t know what you mean by "unsubscription handler", or even by "error thrown while unsubscribing"--what error are you thinking might happen? And `unsubscribe` does not "kill" anything; it just unsubscribes. In your `throw`, are you trying to put the observable into an error state, or trying to throw a generalized JS error, which are two different things? Why are you waiting to unsubscribe? That seems unnecessary, and unsubscribing is unnecessary anyway if the observable ends with an error.

Comment: It is not an rxjs case but system.reactive. Use case is when you have a rabbitmq connection and channel object pass down the chain, and you will need to remove eventlistener, when the stream finish, there's where unsusbcribe handler carry out its work. but when you lose connection , that remove event listener action will throw error since connect is absent.

Comment: If that's the case, the `unsubscribe` implementation should catch and handle the *specific error* that it expects - leaving other errors unhandled. It should not be up to the subscriber to handle a specific error; the subscriber should not have to know anything about the source observable's implementation.

Comment: @cartant thanks for clarifying. Think that make sense, just wondered if it was possible to propagate error back to the chain.